# Inplace upgrade SQL Server 2008R2 to 2019 while retaining IP and computername using Start-DbaMigration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, migration, sql-server-2019, upgrade

I am running existing legacy applications in production using an older version of **SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition**, my goal here is to perform an inline/in-place upgrade to **SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition** while retaining the same IP address and the server name.

How can I achieve this with minimal downtime?

Do I install the new SQL Server 2019 in the same server, and then use https://docs.dbatools.io/#Start-DbaMigration?

However, from the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#upgrades-from-earlier-versions-to-

I cannot see the SQL Server 2019, only SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2016

I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Why do you want to keep same hostname and IP? You can use `cliconfg` for client-side aliases, or create an A-record / CNAME for the old name for the new IP address.

Comment: \@vonPryz so what are the steps to use the cliconfg utility from the server side ?